I can't install linux distros on my computer!
Hello people i got problems installing 32-bit linux distros on my computer: HP ProBook 6460b model XU550AV With Intel Celeron B810 clocked at 1.60 GHZ With HDD Toshiba M101ACF032 Drive Rev AAD AA0/AV001D SATA 320 GB hard drive (i can sometimes format it to 298 GB)
Every linux distro failed to format my hard drive and stayed on the same percentage forever, or they gave an error message saying there was an error fomatting my hard drive
That is rather weir because windows 7 and 10 worked perfectly fine!
I tried Mageia 9, Q4OS, Linux mint based on debian (LMDE6), MX Linux, Budhi, I also tried disabling HP Drivelock but it didn't work either. It may be an long format but when installing windows it sure didn't take hours! Before any linux distro attempt, windows 7 said there was an error with my hdd but smart hdd check never seen an error. I installed windows 10 later and it did work but slow. There could be an hdd error and i must buy a new hdd but i think it will be fine.
Thanks for reading and bye!


It sounds like there is a problem with your harddisk - you should replace it. 2) This site is only for Ubuntu, and there are no 32-bit Ubuntu versions for Intel architecture, so your post is unfortunately off-topic on several levels.


so i am gonna get deleted? :(

I think the question is going to be closed. But you're of course still more than welcome to hang around, and ask another question if it's related to Ubuntu - this is the premise for "Ask Ubuntu".

Feel free to read any question that interests you and the answers to them. That is how we all learn.
